# elasticsearch reindex nested object's element to keyword

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index structured like below:

```
"my_index": {
  "mappings": {
    "my_index": {
      "properties": {
        "adId": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "title": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "creativeStatistics": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "clicks": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "creativeId": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to remove the nested object in a new index and just save the creativeId as a new keyword (to make it clear: I know I will loose the `clicks` data, and it is not important). It means the final new index scheme would be:

```
"my_new_index": {
  "mappings": {
    "my_new_index": {
      "properties": {
        "adId": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "title": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "creativeId": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Right now each row has exactly one creativeStatistics.** and therefore there is no complexity in selecting one of the `creativeId`s.

I know it is possible to reindex using `painless` scripts, but I don't know how can I do that. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "my_old_index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "my_new_index"
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "if (ctx._source.creativeStatistics != null && ctx._source.creativeStatistics.size() > 0) {ctx._source.creativeId = ctx._source.creativeStatistics[0].creativeId; ctx._source.remove('creativeStatistics')}",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a [Pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/pipeline.html) by creating a [Script Processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/script-processor.html) as follows:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/my_pipeline
{
  "description" : "My pipeline",
  "processors" : [
    { "script" : {
        "source": "for (item in ctx.creativeStatistics) { if(item.creativeId!=null) {ctx.creativeId = item.creativeId;} }"
      }  
    },
    {
      "remove": {
        "field": "creativeStatistics"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that if you have multiple nested objects, it would append the last object's `creativeId`. And it would only add `creativeId` if a source document has one in its `creativeStatistics`.

Below is how you can then use reindex query:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "creativeindex_src"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "creativeindex_dest",
    "pipeline": "my_pipeline"
  }
}
```